# Excel Pivot Table Report Filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, powerquery, datamodel

Fed by powerquery queries I have a main Pivot table (2.5+m lines, so not loaded to the sheet nor the data model as I want to use report filters).
Using the "show report filter pages" I split this pivot in multiple subsheets that I export and redistribute.
The problem is that even the subsheets get the full datasource :(, so I'm stuck with:

1. Edit the query, add filter, refresh the pivot an all this for each entity (cumbersome option).
2. Give a pivot with the full source to all entities (not an option).
3. Uncheck the "save source data with file" (now the pivot is not editable anymore for the entities).

Basically I just need to be able to interact with the pivot source trough vba but based on my research this is not possible without refreshing all queries (option 1).
Alternatively, I could fall back on loading to the dataModel, copy the pivot with vba but then it seems I cannot "remove lines" trough vba in the dataModel.

Any other ideas? I cannot believe I'm the only one that finds it stupid that the report filter is not also filtering the pivot source, seems logic to me.

Many thanks,

[Demo file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y617v7pa12gi8g/Main%20file.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: why are the subsheets getting full datasource? And you should be able to interact with pivot source through VBA. Can you provide a file with sample data?

Comment: Added demo file. just to simulate the tech setup with pivot from powerquery. Generated the report filter by country, but you'll see that even in the subsheets you can change the country. Same behaviour if you export the sheet to another workbook. thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to generate a separate sheet for each country. This creates sheets similar to "show report filter pages", but pastes data as plain text.

This is based on the sample sheet provided and if sheets with same name alrady exist it doesn't work right now. But you can add a condition to check the same

```vb
Sub SplitPivot()

Set pvtTable = Worksheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable47")

For Each pvtitem In pvtTable.PivotFields("countries").PivotItems

    pvtTable.PivotFields("countries"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    pvtTable.PivotFields("countries").CurrentPage = pvtitem.Name
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    pvtTable.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ' Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = pvtitem.Name
    
    MsgBox pvtitem.Name & " Done"
        
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This basically copy's the filtered pivot table and paste it as text. same result as option 3 in my question. would it also be possible to do this but instead copy the source data? If I can get the source out of the pivot i can recreate a pivot, assuming that the source by country should be less than 1m lines.

Comment: so you want the pivot to be linked with the query but only show the data of one country?

Comment: Well I'm trying to avoid that as it would oblige me to add the filter in the query, re-run all transformations and all that for each country. I was more thinking to interact with the output of the query. This would be like a breeze if I load the output to a sheet but I have more than 1m lines so that's not an option :(.

Comment: Interacting with Power Query through VBA is not possible.